# Return N columns from a table function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to implement a table function, which I will submit a request with an unknown number of columns. It looks like:

```
SELECT * from TABLE (function())
```

where function, for example`'SELECT x, y FROM z`. I don't know how do this, so I'd like to hear some sort of way to solve, just as an idea.

Comment: A function must return a static datatype, i.e. the datatype returned by the function cannot change, which means this is very difficult. It sounds as though you're telling us your proposed solution to a problem then asking for help with that rather than asking for help with your actual problem, for which there might be a simple solution. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Have a look at [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#BABGFFAI) package. Please describe your actual problem, using DBSM_SQL could be a overkill in your case.

Comment: Actual problem is just that the table function may be any, and we do not know how many columns we select from it. I do not have a more specific example.I would like an approximate solution of the problem in general terms.

Comment: Okey. Actual problem is solution how to return unknown(types and number columns) row from table function to outside select.

Comment: Do you want to return the column names or column values of a table?

Comment: Row with all column values. I think solution near cursors and %ROWTYPE

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is you are getting multiple rows in the o/p when you are using

the function in select statement .

if i create a function as follows:

```
create or replace function get1job

(id in varchar2)

return varchar2 is

tittle jobs.JOB_TITLE%type;

begin

select job_title  into tittle from jobs where job_id=id;

return tittle;

end get1job;
```

and use it in select statement .

i will write :

```
select get_job('AD_PRES') from dual;
```

i will get only one row

if i write :

```
select get_job('AD_PRES') from jobs;
```

the number of rows displayed will be equal to the number of rows in the table jobs.

Comment: I need table function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a fully dynamic SQL, you can insert any SELECT statement and it prints out a corresponding HTML:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HtmlTable(sqlStr IN VARCHAR2) IS

    cur INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    columnCount INTEGER;
    describeColumns DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    res INTEGER;
    c INTEGER;
    aCell  VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('<table>');

    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, sqlStr, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(cur, columnCount, describeColumns);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('<thead><tr>');
    FOR i IN 1..columnCount LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  <td>'||describeColumns(i).COL_NAME||'</td>');
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cur, i, aCell, 4000);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('</tr></thead>');

    res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('<tbody>');
    WHILE (DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cur) > 0) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('<tr>');
        c := 1;
        WHILE (c <= columnCount) LOOP
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cur, c, aCell);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  <td>'||aCell||'</td>');
            c := c + 1;
        END LOOP;       
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('</tr>');
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('</tbody>');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('</table>');
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

END HtmlTable;
```

Use this as a base for your application. Then you can execute it like this:

```
BEGIN
    HtmlTable('SELECT x, y FROM z');
END;
```

Comment: This doesn't return the data, it prints it.

Comment: You should be able to translate a print output into a RETURN clause. Unless we don't know the data type of return value we can not provide any example

Comment: You print multiple times though... you  can only return once. If you can't provide an example that answers the question then why is this an answer to the question?

Comment: I wrote "Use this as a base for your application". Without an exact question we cannot answer excatly, but I assume this example is sufficient to solve the problem unless we know more details.